# How to add multiple layers onto JPanel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I need some help with Java Swing components and its capabilities. I need to add a `JPanel` to a `JFrame` and paint an `Ellipse2D` on it. Onto the `Ellipse2D` I want to add another element, in my case it is a picture (right now I use an `ImageIcon`, maybe wrong). How can I achieve adding the `Ellipse2D` and the picture on the panel as shown in the image I attached?

The reason why I need the images separated is, because I need to change the filling color of the ellipse sometimes.

Thanks for any help.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is to create a custom `JPanel` implementation and override `paintComponent` method.

Inside it, you just do:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw ellipse here

    // Draw your image here. It will be drawn on top of the ellipse.

}
```

This way, you can hold the ellipse fill color in the `CustomPanel` class, and just call `repaint()` method after you change the color.

Comment: Also need to either set the preferredSize or override `getPreferredSize()` so that the component is laid out properly

Comment: How would you draw the Image? `Graphics2D` offers the `drawImage()` method which looks little bit complicated to me, as there is some Observer to set.

Comment: just set the observer to null: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684422/how-does-java-graphics-drawimage-work-and-what-is-the-role-of-imageobserver

Comment: Rather set the observer to `this`

Answer (score 2):

- your idea could be very good described (including code example) in the Oracles tutorial [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)
- notice `JLayer` is available only for Java7, but its based on (for Java6) [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/)
- you can use (I'm using) `GlassPane` too, with the same / similair output to the Swing GUI

EDIT

quite easy and nice output is by using [OverlayLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html), there is possible to overlay `J/Component`(s) with `Graphics` e.g., [a few examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/OverlayLayoutforlayoutmanagementofcomponentsthatlieontopofoneanother.htm)

Answer (score 0):

take the two images as image icons like

```
ImageIcon car=new ImageIcon("image path");
ImageIcon elipse=new ImageIcon("image path");
```

add those two image icons two label

```
JLabel carLabel=new JLabel(car);
JLabel ellipseLabel=new JLabel(ellipse);
```

and set the position of ellipse and car

```
carLabel.setBounds(0,0,50,50);
ellipseLabel.setBounds(10,10,50,50);
```