# Background image on JPanel and combo box

Tags: java, swing, combobox, background-image

I was wondering if it was possible to place a created combo box on top of a Background picture placed on a JPanel. I am trying to do this however, i think the background image is overlapping my combo boxes so it doesn't appear. Any one know a clean way of having a background image on a JPanel with combo box on top and it positioned using box layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the setComponentZOrder() method.

Here is an example: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/01/21/swing-internals-paint-order

(Check the JavaDoc for more detailed information: [setComponentZOrder() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, and maybe more used, would see you override `JPanel` `paintComponent` and draw image directly to the `Graphic`s object:

```
JFrame frame=...;

final BufferedImage bg=ImageIO.read(new URL("http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp6700/icons/DukeWithHelmet.png"));

JPanel p=new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.drawImage(bg,0,0,null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {//so our JPanel will fit the image entirely
        return new Dimension(bg.getWidth(),bg.getHeight());
    } 
};

frame.add(p);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: In general, the ImageObserver argument passed to a drawImage method should be `this`, not null.  Yes, it probably doesn't matter when you use a BufferedImage, but it's good practice.

Comment: Not _essential_ with `ImageIO.read()`; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1684422/230513).

Comment: +1 to trashgod, @VGR, IMO it cannot be good practice if its unnecessary, than its just unnecessary... Good practice IMO is doing something that can be done in order to make code work more effectively and adding `this` does not. Its would actually be wrong in the context of my post.